Existence of diffeomorphism between 2-dimensional torus and $\mathbb{R} / \Lambda$ which preserves fixed pairs of fundamental group generators.
I'm going through A primer on mapping class groups by Benson Farb and Dan Margalit. In the chapter 10.2 The Teichmuller space of 2-d torus $T^2$ is proved to be $\mathbb{H}.$ While showing that there is a bijective correspondence
$$ \text{Teich} T^2 \leftrightarrow \{\text{marked lattices in } \mathbb{R}^2 \}/ ∼,\text{ where the equivalence relation is generated by Euclidean isometries and homotheties,}$$ there is

Fix a standard ordered generating set for $\Pi_1(T^2)$. The ordered generating
set for a marked lattice $\Lambda$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ descends to an ordered generating set for
$\Pi_1 (\mathbb{R}^2/\Lambda)$. It is possible to find a diffeomorphism $\varphi : T^2 \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^2/\Lambda$ that
takes the first and second generators of $\Pi_1(T^2)$ to the first and second gen-
erators for $\Pi_1 (\mathbb{R}^2/\Lambda)$. We can pull back the flat metric on $ \mathbb{R}^2/\Lambda$ via this
diffeomorphism in order to obtain a flat metric on $T^2$. We can scale this
metric to obtain a unit-area metric, and hence a point in $ \text{Teich} T^2$.

I believe $ \mathbb{R}^2/\Lambda$ is constructed as in the first answer here - we take the two geodesics and their tangent vectors at the point of intersection and make it the generators of the lattice as the tangent space $T \ T^2$ is trivial.
I can't find, how is the existence of such a diffeomorphism provided?

These are interesting issues, but they are all mathematically distinct questions, and you should keep in mind our guidelines for asking one question per post. Let me suggest you edit your post so as to narrow its focus down to one solid question, leaving remaining questions for later posts.

The proof is basically just a bit of linear algebra.
Start with the fact that $T^2 = S^1 \times S^1$ can itself be expressed in the form $\mathbb R^2 / \Lambda_0$ where
$$\Lambda_0 = 2 \pi \mathbb Z \times 2 \pi \mathbb Z
$$
That is, there is a homeomorphism
$$\mathbb R^2 / \Lambda_0 \to T^2
$$
which is (well) defined by
$$(x,y) \mapsto (e^{ix},e^{iy})
$$
Now you can use the fact that any two lattices are group theoretically isomorphic, in particular any lattice $\Lambda$ is isomorphic to $\Lambda_0$: the lattice $\Lambda_0$ has a positively oriented basis $\{(2\pi,0),(0,2\pi)\}$ over $\mathbb Z$, we can also choose a positively oriented basis $\{u,v\}$ for $\Lambda$ over $\mathbb Z$, and the isomorphism is given by the formula
$$T(2\pi m, 2 \pi n) \mapsto mu+nv
$$
This is the restriction of a linear transformation of $\mathbb R^2$:
$$T(2\pi x, 2 \pi y) = xu + yv
$$
and this linear transformation gives a well-defined formula for a homeomorphism from $\mathbb R / \Lambda_0$ to $\mathbb R / \Lambda$.

Thanks, I've finally understood the idea behind the proof.
